# referencing pointer as argument of function and changing its referenced value

Tags: c

hello i have a question which is very basic and quite confusing for beginner

let me say there's a code like this

```
typedef struct st {
 int a;
 int b;
} structure

structure gee;
gee.a =3;
gee.b =5;

void foo(void (*st)){
 g->a += g->b;
}
```

so what i want to do with function foo is make a = a+b; which both are in structure.

and also i want to use pointer *st as argument of function foo.

and i got dereferencing error again and again. what is problem with my code? and what should i do??

Comment: Please show us the code using `foo`

Comment: what is `g` ? should it not be `st` ?

Comment: in your `foo` function, you pass `*st`, but use `g->a`...is this intentional?

Comment: also not that `st` is `void` pointer and `g` is pointing to your `struct`

Comment: oh i am sorry for using g. it is st.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to use the correct types. (You should rarely have to use `void*`.)  Use `&` operator to get the address (create a pointer-to).

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct st {
 int a;
 int b;
} structure;                  // <--- You were missing a semicolon;

structure g_gee = { 3, 5 };   // This guy is global
// You can't do this, you have to use a struct initializer.
//gee.a =3;                    
//gee.b =5; 

void add_a_b(structure* g) {
    g->a += g->b;
}

void print_structure(const char* msg, structure* s) {
    printf("%s: a=%d b=%d\n", msg, s->a, s->b);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    structure local_s = { 4, 2 };        // This guy is local to main()

    // Operate on local
    print_structure("local_s before", &local_s);
    add_a_b( &local_s );
    print_structure("local_s after", &local_s);

    // Operate on global
    print_structure("g_gee before", &g_gee);
    add_a_b( &g_gee );        
    print_structure("g_gee after", &g_gee);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
local_s before: a=4 b=2
local_s after: a=6 b=2
g_gee before: a=3 b=5
g_gee after: a=8 b=5
```

Comment: @user2375570 You're welcome. Welcome to StackOverflow! Remember to up-vote any answers that help, and "accept" the one that best answers your question.

Comment: @YHG That's just how it works, there can only be one accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick.

```
typedef struct {
 int a;
 int b;
} structure;

void foo(structure * st){
 st->a += st->b;
}

int main (void)
{
  structure gee;
  gee.a =3;
  gee.b =5;
  foo(&gee);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: i will try this immediately. would you please get me some hint or shortcut to learn difference between * and & ?

Comment: The `*` in a declaration (return type, function parameter, variable declaration...) means "pointer". `structure * st` means `st` is a pointer and contains a memory location of type `structure`. The reference operator `&` used in a statement is usually refered to as "address-of"-operator. foo(&gee) passes the address of gee into foo(), which in turn will be the value of the pointer `st`.